# Optimal format for office suites portability

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice, word-processing

I really don't know how to ask this a better way. I have tried googling, but even Google isn't of much help if you don't know what exactly to search for.

For some reason, LibreOffice seems to generate ODF Text and MS Word XML (odt and docx) that both appear to be corrupted when opened by Word 2010, and vice-versa. Word and Writer can always recover them intact, but I wouldn't really want to "recover" my files every time I open it on a different OS (I have both Windows and Linux at home and work and there's no way to avoid using both).

So can anyone tell me why either word processor thinks the other's files is corrupted, and how to solve it, or what format would be fully portable between the two?

The only features I want the files to support are page sizing, header/footer and basic centering/justifying text functions. I thought RTF would work, but I'm not sure it saves the page formatting and I can't test it right now. Thanks in advance!